# get body class by active parent menu item

Tags: php, css, joomla

example:

menuitem 1
menuitem 1.1
menuitem 1.2
menuitem 1.2.1
menuitem 2
menuitem 3

I now have:

```
<?php $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();?>
<body class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?> ">
```

So I load the body class from the active menu item. I'd like that to stay the same. The thing I need is to hide certain menu item's when for example menuitem 1 is active. So when that happens I need to assign a class to menuitem 2.

That way when I navigate down 1.1 it keeps the menu items hidden.

**Found a solution:**

```
<?php
$menu =& JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$class = extractpath($active->route);
function extractpath($string){
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/',$string,$m);   
return $m[0];
}

?>
  <body<?php if ($class) echo ' class="' . $class . '"'; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the parent - $menu->getActive()->parent

To get the Title of the parent - $menu->getItem([id])->name

Comment: I dont want to it do anything to the body class. See edited original post. But maybe it will work, ill test it out!